# Forecast based on indicators

Tags: forecasting

I wanna forecast a specific timeseries. I have monthly datapoints for about 8 years. (From now on called target).

In addition to that i have 15 indicator timeseries (also monthly with about 8 years of data) where i know (or hope) that they influence the target.

I know by how many months this timerseries are leading my target one (lag in months), and i also have a value ranging from 0-1 for each of the timeseries which indicates how sure i am that the timeseries is influcening my target. Since i only take the best 500 timeseries this value is mainly above 0,7.

The picture below shows the target timeseries in black, the green timeseries are my already shifted indicators (shifted by the number of months they are leading the target).
The vertical line represents the (fictional) current time.
The red line are the actual values of my target which i wanna forecast.

[image]

Naively this seems quite simple since i could just calculate the average pitch of all the indicators and use it to extend the target timeseries.
But i am searching for a more sophisticated statistcal approach.

What is the best method or model to make an accurate forecast of my target timeseries based on the 15 indicator timeseries?
I already tried an ARIMA model but couldn't apply it to my data.

I would love to have concrete code examples in python or similiar to understand it and play around with it.

For reference, here is the same plot as above but without shifting the indicators:
[image]